# Logins Not being used in last one month

Tags: sql-server, security, audit, logins

I have a requirement to create a query which can get the logins details which were not used in last one month.
I have tried several way like extended events and audit tracing. But i'm unable to get the list of the logins that were not being used in last one month,
Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you explain what did you try with audit tracing? That should work.

Comment: I have enabled the login audit to tract both successful and failed login in error log. But the challenge is to write a query which should accept a date as a parameter and give the result as the logins which were not being used.

Comment: I suggest use an extended event trace for all login for 30 days. The one does not show up in trace are not being used.

Comment: Yes, but how to query the rows of a extended events. I have played with the sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file function, but unable to write a query for the same

Comment: If you have collected extended events data already, then describing that and asking how to query it might be a more direct approach than just saying you were unable to write a query, so you gave up and switched to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use xp_readerrorlog multiple times to insert all the log file.
below is the simple modification of code provided in above answer

```
create table #t (dt datetime, procc varchar(100), txt varchar(8000));
insert into #t exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Login succeeded for user';
insert into #t exec xp_readerrorlog 0,2,N'Login succeeded for user';
insert into #t exec xp_readerrorlog 0,3,N'Login succeeded for user';

select distinct substring(txt, 27, CHARINDEX('''', substring(txt, 27, 8000)) 
- 1) as login_name
into #t_logged
from #t
where dt between @start_date and @end_date;


select name
from sys.server_principals
where type in ('S', 'U')

except

select login_name
from #t_logged;
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you've already added the successful login auditing to the instance, you can dump the error log data to a #temp table, then parse the individual login names, and then find all the rows in sys.server_principals that don't exist in the filtered data.

```
CREATE TABLE #x
(
  LogDate datetime,
  ProcessInfo nvarchar(max),
  [Text] nvarchar(max)
);

DECLARE @dt datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());

INSERT #x(LogDate, ProcessInfo, [Text]) 
  EXEC master.sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Login succeeded', NULL, 
    @dt;

;WITH p(pattern) AS 
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING([text], CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), [text]) + 1, 500) FROM #x
),
x(name) AS 
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(pattern, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), pattern)-1) FROM p
)
SELECT p.name, p.create_date, p.is_disabled
  FROM sys.server_principals AS p
  WHERE p.principal_id > 255      -- no system logins
  AND p.name NOT LIKE N'##%##'    -- e.g. ##MS_AgentSigningCertificate
  AND p.name NOT LIKE N'NT %\%'   -- e.g. NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  AND p.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM x);
```

Assuming that perhaps your current error log file is less than a month old, you can see the following article for ideas on searching more than one error log at a time:

- [Search multiple SQL Server Error Logs at the same time](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3135/search-multiple-sql-server-error-logs-at-the-same-time/)

---

**In the future**, I would rather create an audit specification or extended events session to avoid polluting the error log.

```
CREATE SERVER AUDIT GoodLogins
TO FILE (FILEPATH = 'C:\temp\GoodLogins\');
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION GoodLoginsSpec
  FOR SERVER AUDIT GoodLogins
  ADD (SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP);
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT GoodLogins WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

Then you can just query all of the audit data:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());

;WITH x(name) AS 
(
  SELECT server_principal_name
    FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('C:\temp\GoodLogins\*', NULL, NULL)
    WHERE event_time >= @dt
    GROUP BY server_principal_name 
)
SELECT p.name
  FROM sys.server_principals AS p
  WHERE p.principal_id > 255      -- no system logins
  AND p.name NOT LIKE N'##%##'    -- e.g. ##MS_AgentSigningCertificate
  AND p.name NOT LIKE N'NT %\%'   -- e.g. NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  AND p.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM x);
```

Comment: Your solution will output all the windows groups because no one can log in as a group, but only as a single windows account. My solution isn't better because it does not treat logins-groups at all, but at least it does not output them as "not being used" (think what will happen if the result logins are destinated to be dropped!). The complete solution should analyze windows groups to see if there is any group where no one member was logged on in the given period

Comment: @sepucic Well, if the OP is even using groups, he/she could specify and maybe we could come up with a better solution. The question asked for logins (and may even be restricted to SQL auth logins), and you can certainly filter `server_principals` by type if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change your login auditing using script like this

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'AuditLevel', REG_DWORD, 3
```

or using SSMS: server properties -> Security tab -> Login auditing -> both failed and successful logins. After this change you should restart your server and it will log into error log successful logins too. Then you can parse your server error log and find out all the login events, for example using this code:

```
xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Login succeeded for user'
```

So you can find who was logged on during 1 month, and using EXCEPT with sys.server_principals you'll find who was not logged on.
You should also cycle your error log (maybe using a job, once a day) for preventing it outgrowth

......................
This is the final code:

```
create table #t (dt datetime, procc varchar(100), txt varchar(8000));
insert into #t exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Login succeeded for user';

select distinct substring(txt, 27, CHARINDEX('''', substring(txt, 27, 8000)) - 1) as login_name
into #t_logged
from #t
where dt between @start_date and @end_date;


select name
from sys.server_principals
where type in ('S', 'U')

except

select login_name
from #t_logged;
```

just provide @start_date and @end_date and be sure you've examined all your error logs (in my example I use only one error log file)

Comment: I have already performed what you have suggested, but the challenge is to create a query which should read from error log and get the list of the logins which were not being used in a specified range

Comment: ok, I'll edit my answer providing the whole code

Comment: Have a look here this might help you: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3171/identify-sql-server-databases-that-are-no-longer-in-use/